# Defining an Implies operation that works for Boolean matrices

Tags: matrix, boolean-computation

I have two Boolean matrices, that both have dimensions m x n. I want to create a function `TableImplies`, which would return `True` if one matrix piecewise implies the other; in other words, given matrices `A = (a_ij)` and `B = (b_ij)`, then

```
TableImplies[A, B] = true if for all i and j, a_ij => b_ij.
```

For example:

```
truePattern = Table[True, {2}, {3}]
```

> {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}}

```
falsePattern = Table[False, {2}, {3}]
```

> {{False, False, False}, {False, False, False}}

```
TableImplies[falsePattern, truePattern]
```

> True

```
TableImplies[truePattern, falsePattern]
```

> False

```
randomPattern = Table[RandomInteger[] == 1, {2}, {3}]
```

> {{True, True, False}, {True, True, False}}

```
TableImplies[randomPattern, randomPattern]
```

> True

What I got so far:

```
ElementWiseImplies[x_, y_] = Implies[x, y]

SetAttributes[ElementWiseImplies, Listable]

ElementWiseImplies[RandomPattern, RandomPattern]
```

> {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}}

Now this is all good. Next:

```
Apply[And, %, {0, 2}]
```

> True

That seems to work. But if I do like this:

```
TableImplies[x_, y_] = Apply[And, ElementWiseImplies[x, y], {0, 2}]
```

> x && y

the result is not what I wish. I understand, why this is happening: *Mathematica* applies `And` not to the result of `ElementWiseImplies`, but to the expression `ElementWiseImplies[x, y]` itself, so the result becomes `And[x, y]`, which is not what I expected.

What should I do? Use local variable `x =  ElementWiseImplies[x, y]`; and then `Apply[And, x, {0, 2}]`? Or is there more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tableImplies[a_, b_] := And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Implies, {a, b}, 2]
```

usage

```
a = Table[aa[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
b = Table[bb[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
tableImplies[a, b]
(*

(aa[1, 1] \[Implies] bb[1, 1]) && 
(aa[1, 2] \[Implies] bb[1, 2]) && 
(aa[2, 1] \[Implies] bb[2, 1]) && 
(aa[2, 2] \[Implies] bb[2, 2])

*)
```